# When i open my admin panel in django they show me the error

Tags: python, django, admin, panel

[image]

Please anyone tell me what I can do. whenever I save  my project and open the admin-panel they show the error "

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from home.models import Task

admin. site.register(Task)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    taskTitle=models.CharField( max_length=50)
    taskDescription=models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tasktitle
```

```
TypeError: Field 'None' expected a number but got 1."
```

Comment: You need to update your question with your `admin.py` and `models.py` to better understand which model or admin registration is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a mismatch in your schema definition and your database models. If you can, inspect the database schema inside your database and check if they match with your schema definition.

If you have changed the models schema after you initially created the database, you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`.

If that doesn't solve it and you don't have much data you can try removing the database and creating it again. You can do so by deleting the database file if it's a sqlite file inside your project and running `python manage.py migrate`. In this case you should do `python manage.py createsuperuser` again and make a super user to be able to login in the admin panel.